# explain this code with decltype in it

Tags: c++, decltype

```
([] () -> decltype(std::cout << "Hello") {
    return std::cout << "Hello";
}()) << ", world!";
```

prints `Hello, world!`.

I simply don't understand what's going on here. Can someone explain it to me in simple terms?

Comment: This is a lambda function that is defined and immediately executed. Read about these stuffs.

Comment: That's equivalent to `[]{return std::cout << "Hello";}() << ", world!";`, by the way.

Comment: First they ruined my beloved readable Python language with these monstrosities, now they've done it to C++. If the ISO bods ever get it into their heads to do the same to C, I'll track them down and beat them to death with wet celery sticks (to prolong the agony) :-)

Comment: @paxdiablo: Ewww... I hate celery... note to self: do NOT join C committee.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
([] () -> decltype(std::cout << "Hello")
```

This creates a lambda (in-place function) with the same return type that the expression `std::cout << "Hello"` has - that's `std::ostream&`.  The `[]` starts the lambda, the `()` is an empty parameter list, the `->` preceeds the return type, and `decltype(X)` is equivalent to the type of the expression X.  Then the function body:

```
{
    return std::cout << "Hello";
}
```

Then the function is called... that outputs "Hello" and returns the stream....

```
 ())
```

And finally, to the returned stream, a little more text is sent...

```
 << ", world!";
```